# Irrigation system B-Hyve with manifold away from the faucet

Tags: faucet, pvc, irrigation, outdoorfaucet

I am using 3 B-hyve Smart Hose Faucet Timers to schedule watering. The current system is connected as:

Faucet ---- ~35 ft garden hose ----- backflow preventer ---- 4-Way Hose Faucet Splitter --- 3x (pressure regulator + Smart Faucet Timer)

This setup is problematic because of the garden hose. At the faucet there used to be pressure regulator but it broke and the water was sprinkling for days before i noticed. Now the hose disconnected from the faucet (it is connected to the faucet using 5/8 in. Metal Female Mender from Homedepot).

The problem is that the system above is always connected directly to the faucet without the hose in between but I do not want to uselessly drag 3x ~35 ft irrigation tubing. Also it is at the side of the house where wifi is not accessible.

Can someone suggest a better setup that would be affordable (max 30 USD). I am considering a new hose which would have a factory fitted connector to the faucet. I was thinking about running a PVC tube up to the manifold but I have no idea how to connect the PVC to the faucet (I am limited with tools and do not want to buy things just for single use). But the PVC is white (the current hose is black) and I am in central Florida, the water from the hose in summer is over 150F in the afternoon.

Comment: Even white pvc will get hot but not as bad as black or green. there are both male and female hose ends available for pvc pipe, no special tools required just accurate cuts.

Comment: @EdBeal Will the connection faucet-PVC be more reliable than to the garden hose?

Comment: Above ground I would want the flex that a garden hose would provide but if trenched I would want pvc. The white pvc would be cooler than the green but it may still warm up if on the surface.